# Play 2.0.4 Catch-all route always hits

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

At the end of my routes file I put a catch-all route to catch requests which wasn't catch previously and pass it to my own router (for further processing):

```
GET    /*nameUrl      controllers.Application.router(nameUrl: String)
```

of course there are many other routes BEFORE that line. The big surprise for me is that the catch-all is hitten every time, even if previous  route is hitten as well, so if I'm opening address `domain.tld/test` it displays me both logs in the console `Test action hit!` AND  `Custom router hit!` . There is a simplified sample:

```
public static Result test() {
    Logger.debug("Test action hit!");
    return ok();
}

public static Result router(String nameUrl) {
    Logger.debug("Custom router hit!");
    return ok();
}
```

Routes (in this order)

```
GET    /test          controllers.Application.test
GET    /*nameUrl      controllers.Application.router(nameUrl: String)
```

What do I want to get:

I want to get url's for articles with my router ie `domain.tld/category_1/article_title` without any prefix before it, of course if I change catch all to something stable it won't get double hits anymore:

```
GET    /news/*nameUrl      controllers.Application.router(nameUrl: String)
domain.tld/news/category_1/article_title
```

however I really want to avoid `/news/` segment. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I repeated it and had the same problem with Chromium (core of Google Chrome), but not with Firefox.

With Global.java I analyzed the request.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public Action onRequest(Http.Request request, Method method) {
        Logger.info("request-path: " + request.path());
        return super.onRequest(request, method);
    }
}
//output:
[info] application - request-path: /favicon.ico
```

For every GET /test request Chromium tries to load the favicon.

So, include the following in conf/routes:

```
GET  /favicon.ico   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="favicon.ico")
```

Comment: +1 The favicon.ico route should be added along with the assets route when creating a new project using `play new`.