# routing to a static file in play! framework 2.0

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, playframework, playframework-2.0

For SEO purpose, i'm tring to make some files accessible from url like http://example.ca/robots.txt but i'm confronted to a strange issue. The files are accessible with firefox but chromium and google bots can't get those files !

my routes:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# Robots and Humans files
GET     /$file<(robots|humans).txt>             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

GET     /$file<MJ12_576CD562EFAFA1742768BA479A39BFF9.txt>                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: Do you get 404 errors?  Are you sure that something isn't being cached that would cause this?

Comment: Take a look for another question, where Chrome makes strange things :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13103936/1066240 Thanx to @Schleichardt I solved it by adding favicon, check with `onRequest` what happens.

Comment: i was testing with empty file and seems like chrome consider empty file as broken link ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but try:

```
GET     /robots.txt             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="robots.txt")
GET     /humans.txt             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="humans.txt")

GET     /MJ12_576CD562EFAFA1742768BA479A39BFF9.txt                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="MJ12_576CD562EFAFA1742768BA479A39BFF9.txt")
```

Comment: Use this for `favicon.ico` too. I'm putting this here for google searches.